# Reporting means and standard deviations when using linear mixed-effects

Tags: mixed-model, standard-deviation, mean, reporting

I'm analyzing data from an experiment where participants responded to a large set of stimulus. Such stimuli were divided intro three experimental conditions. The dependent variable was the response time. My doubt is how to report mean response times if I'm analyzing the data with linear mixed-effect models. When I analyze the data with repeated measures ANOVA, I report SD and mean response times of participants; that is, I calculate the average RT for each participant in each condition, and then I calculate the average of those averages, and I show the average RT for each condition (e.g., condition 1: 680 [sd = 100], condition 2: 610 [sd = 120], etc.) However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to report sd and mean RTs when using linear mixed-effects. Should I report the average of all the data points of each condition?